# How to sort 2 list's based on first list

Tags: c#, linq, list, c#-4.0, sorting

There are 2 list

1. list_int
2. ptdPoints

I need to sort the ptdPoints based on list_in

My current code is as follows:-

```
List<int> list_int = new List<int>() {1,9,3};
List<PointF> ptdPoints= new List<PointF>();
ptdPoints.Add(new PointF(20,10));
ptdPoints.Add(new PointF(10,80));
ptdPoints.Add(new PointF(60,30));
```

How to order list_int and ptdPoints based on the ascending order of list_int

Here the result is as follows=>

- 1=>(20,10)
- 3=>(60,30)
- 10=>(10,80)

So I am arranging the list_int in the ascending order and the corresponding value in other index also changes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: List 2 has nothing to do with 1?

Comment: I want to sort the first list and the corresponding list should also be sorted in the same order

Comment: is the order just the order of the y values?

Comment: No order is just a variable it can hold any value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work, but only if the `order` list is the same size as the `ptdPoints` list:

```
List<int> order = new List<int>() { 1, 9, 3 };
List<PointF> ptdPoints = new List<PointF>() { new PointF(20, 10), new PointF(10, 80), new PointF(60, 30) };

var result = order.Zip(ptdPoints, (left, right) => new {left, right})
                  .OrderBy(a => a.left)
                  .Select(a => a.right)
                  .ToList();
```

You basicaly merge the two list into an anonymous object, ordering on the element of the first list and outputing the second list only. Note that this will **not** change the original list.

**Edit:** For details on how this work, you can read up [these entries on LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) and this one on [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx).

```
order.Zip(ptdPoints, (left, right) => new {left, right})
```

This line will take the `order` list, and 'zip' in an orderly manner (that means the first element of the first list with the first of second and so on). the `(left, right) => new {left, right}` is an anonymous function taking an element from the first list (`left`) and an element of the second list (`right`) and outputing a new anonymous object with two members: `int left` and `PointF right`.

```
.OrderBy(a => a.left)
```

[`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) specifies which of the object properties you want your ordering to be performed. Following the first line, the input to the function `a => a.left` will be the anonymous object created before. We then say: from these elements, order them based on the `left` property. Since this is an anonymous object joining your points and your original integers, ordering on the integer on the anonymous object will order the points based on your integers.

```
.Select(a => a.right)
```

[`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) projects an object into another. This line says: from now on, I want to manipulate only the objects that are in the `right` properties of my anonymous object, essentialy projecting your anonymous object to your original `PointF` list.

The next step is to create a new list off this sequence.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Ahahah. We're bound to answer the same questions. ;)

Comment: It works!! but plz also explain how it works I m very much interested in this code.

Comment: @andikatdennis See my edit for a breakdown.

Answer (score 7):

Whatever you are trying to do, it's probably a better solution if you put the data of both lists into one object and one list, and then sort this list.

Something like this (untested, written on the fly):

```
class OrderedPoint
{
    public int Order {get;set;}
    public PointF Point {get;set;}

    public static int CompareByOrder(OrderedPoint x, OrderedPoint y)
    {
        return x.Order.CompareTo(y.Order);
    }
}

List<OrderedPoint> list;
// TODO: Fill it
list.Sort(OrderedPoint.CompareByOrder);
```

Comment: You may want to back this up with code, then. As it stands, this looks like a simple suggestion, not a solution to the questioner's problem.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Code added

Comment: +1 As this is the most sane answer, guiding the original poster toward good practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
ptdPoints.Select((o, i) => new { Point = 0; Int = order[i] }).OrderBy(a => a.Int).Select(a => a.Point);
```